# CKEditor - Inline editing: browser POSTs not full content

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, ckeditor, inline-editing

**Here is browser script to save "edit_body" field:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#save_editable").click(function(){
  var edit_body = $("#edit_body").html();
  setTimeout(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url:'http://my-url.com/my_editor.php?id_to_update=123',
    type:'POST',
    data:{edit_body:edit_body},
    success:function(data){
     if(data=='1'){
      alert('Saved');
     }
    }
   });
  },5000);
 });
});
</script>
```

**The server do next:**

```
if(@$_POST["edit_body"]){
 $id_to_update=intval($_GET['id_to_update']);
 $edit_body=iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', html_entity_decode($_POST["edit_body"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"));
 if(mysql_query(sprintf('update my_table set body="%s" where id="%s";',$edit_body,$id_to_update)){
  print '1';
 }
}
```

**The problem is:**
When "edit_body" contain a lot of text it successfully saves but **not full** content.
The weaker the browser is, the less text is saved.
In this case I've made setTimeout function with 5 sec delay. But it don't help some times..

How could I tell browser to wait for processing variable "edit_body" before Ajax post..?

Comment: *The weaker the browser* What in the world does that mean? Did you look at what is being sent up to the server? Is it all there in the post request when you look at it from the console/Fiddler? Are you cancelling the click action of `save_editable`?

Comment: When I have more than 20 tabs open in browser it works slower and uses more time to get variable from the field in page. Everything is ok with server side. I am not canceling anything. Just waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using CKEditor's getData() method to get the document instead of jQuery's html() method:

```
var edit_body = CKEDITOR.instances["edit_body"].getData();
```